# Python: Which method to use for file operations?

Tags: python, linux

I am interested in performing file operations, such as move/copy/delete, on my Linux system. I understand that one way to achieve this is using os.system() combined with a bash command (mv, cp, rm). I also have discovered other modules that seem to be dedicated to such operations, namely the shutil module. I am having trouble deciding between these options. I am only interested in performance and reliability; I am not interested in compatibility (with other systems).

What are the use cases of each option? Advantages/Disadvantages?

Are there any other options that you would recommend?

Comment: Use `shutil`, you are not able to handle errors using `os.system()`.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Thank you that sounds like a strong point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the modules as they are typically faster. shutil is the main python module that I've come across but if you do need to directly access the terminal/command line, try using subprocess.popen or os.popen as they return useful information.

Also, there are many disadvantages to os.system() which can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-still-a-bad-practice-to-use-OS-system-in-Python-if-the-argument-is-a-string-constant-and-not-a-command-taken-from-the-user).
Including the fact that you cannot handle errors, as  Maurice Meyer said.